# PubNub AngularJS error in push config: 'Pubnub.push.addChannels' is undefined

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, apple-push-notifications, pubnub

Using PubNub and trying to setup push for ios (apns)  [per their docs](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/javascript/api-reference-sdk-v4#subscribe).

The following generates the error:

```
  var initPubnubPush = function(token) {
    Pubnub.push.addChannels(
      {
          channels: ['my_first_channel'],
          device: token,
          pushGateway: 'apns' // apns, gcm, mpns
      },
      function(status) {
          if (status.error) {
              console.log("operation failed w/ error:", status);
          } else {
              console.log("operation done!")
          }
      }
  );
}
```

I have their publish/subscribe working on the channel `my_first_channel` and push should work when the app is in background. The token is valid and is returned from

```
pushNotification.register(
      tokenHandler,
      errorHandler,
      {
          'badge':'true',
          'sound':'true',
          'alert':'true',
          'ecb':'onNotificationAPN'
      }
  );

  function tokenHandler(token) {
        // This is a device token you will need later to send a push
        // Store this to PubNub to make your life easier :-)
      initPubnubPush(token);
    }
```

The complete error in Safari console while running on real iPhone device:

```
Error in Success callbackId: PushPlugin63370093 : TypeError: 
Pubnub.push.addChannels is not a function. 
(In 'Pubnub.push.addChannels', 'Pubnub.push.addChannels' is undefined)
```

Can't find anything  in google for this error.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there is a bug in the [PubNub Angular library](https://github.com/pubnub/pubnub-angular) and that method `push.addChannels` is not properly delegated.